# SQL query to get state,then city and address and zip

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data from database in this format:

```
    state
    |__city
    |  |__address
    |  |__zip
```

I want all unique states and cities with all addresses and zip codes concatenated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT
  state,
  GROUP_CONCAT('(',address,';)') AS address,
  GROUP_CONCAT('(',zip,';)') AS zip
FROM location
WHERE   
  sername='ABC@gmail.com'
GROUP BY state,city
```

**UPDATE**
There is problem with concatenation. I want the data in this format:

```
state        city     address               zip     
Karnataka   BANGALORE   (sdbsbd);(dsdsds);  NULL
```

and I'm getting data as

```
state        city     address               zip     
Karnataka   BANGALORE   (sdbsbd);,(dsdsds); NULL
```

I don't want the comma in the address:

```
;,
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The query produces results that would seem to satisfy the question.  Is there a reason why you don't think it is correct?

Comment: Please post a data record in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the SEPERATOR argument in the GROUP_CONCAT() function.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT state, GROUP_CONCAT('(',address,';)' SEPARATOR '') as        
address,GROUP_CONCAT('(',zip,';)' SEPARATOR '') as zip FROM location Where   
username='ABC@gmail.com' GROUP BY state,city"
```